# Ember cli broken by new release of ember data?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, firebase, ember-cli

Hi i am an ember noob and when i upgraded to the latest ember data i got these warnings:

Update: I have two versions of my app one built without ember-cli and the other one with ember cli both apps are exactly the same they both log these messages out to the console:

DEPRECATION: Usage of `snapshot.constructor` is deprecated, use `snapshot.type` instead.

DEPRECATION: Using DS.Snapshot.get() is deprecated. Use .attr(), .belongsTo() or .hasMany() instead.

The first one pops up twice and the second one once right after i click the alert here is the code:

The difference is that the app built without ember-cli works!

It seems to me that this must be a problem with ember-cli

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    sortProperties:["time"],
    sortAscending:true,
    start:new Date(),
    count:0,
    incorrect:0,
    startReview:true,
    showHighScores:false,

    actions:{

        startReview:function(){
            this.set('startReview',false);
            this.set("showHighScores",false);
            this.start = new Date();
            this.count = 0;
            this.incorrect = 0;
            console.log(this.count);
        },

        showHighScores:function(){
            this.toggleProperty("showHighScores");
        },

        checkCorrectness:function(word){
            var textArray = this.get("model.text").split(" ");
            var length = textArray.length;
            if(word === textArray[this.count]){ 
                console.log("correct");
                this.count++;
                console.log(this.count);
            }else{
                console.log("Incorrect");
                this.incorrect++;
            }
            if(length === this.count){
                var finish = new Date();
                var time = finish-this.start;
                var accuracy = (this.count/(this.count+this.incorrect)*100);
                **alert("You took "+time/1000+" seconds! With "+accuracy+"% accuracy!");**
```

> Right after i click this alert the deprecation warnings appear

```
                this.saveResult(time);
                this.set('startReview',true);
            }
        },
    },
```

> I think the set and get in the code below must be the offenders but i
>   dont know how to change them to comlply with the latest update to
>   ember data

```
    randomizer:function(){
        this.set("randomArray",this.get("model.text").split(" ").randomize());      
    }.observes("startReview"),

    saveResult:function(timeTaken){
        var date = new Date(),
            userName = "TimTheGreat";


        var score = this.store.createRecord('score',{
            userName:userName,
            date:date,
            time:timeTaken,
            verse:this.get('model'),
        });

        var controller = this;
        var scores = controller.get("model.scores");
        score.save().then(function(score){
            scores.addObject(score).then(function(){
                controller.get("model").save();
            });

        });
    }
});
```

Heres a link to the blog post about the release of the latest version of ember-data http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/14/ember-data-1-0-beta-15-released.html

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. This being a Q&A forum, it's hard to find a specific *Q* here. This reads more like a bug report.

Answer (score 2):

Not being able to see the whole thing makes it difficult to see where your problem lies.

If it's any help, I ran into a similar issue because I had created custom serializers (the note you linked to for ember data 15 beta specifically calls out that the change is scoped to serializers) and inside of my over-ridden serializer code I was doing record.get('someproperty') instead of the newer record.attr('someproperty') that they want you to do now.

Are you rolling your own adapter / serializers or using something someone else put together? It's entirely possible that whatever you're using there hasn't been updated properly.

UPDATE:
according to comments, you're using the firebase adapter which apparently has a known issue with ember data 0.1.15b. See https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/issues/226

Essentially, they are using:

`json[payloadKey] = Ember.A(record.get(key)).mapBy('id');`

in their serializeHasMany function where it should now read:

`json[payloadKey] = Ember.A(record.attr(key)).mapBy('id');`

Comment: i am using the firebase adapter

Comment: this is a bug in their serializer (or at least is a bug if you want to run ember data b15). Their serializeHasMany has a line in it that says: json[payloadKey] = Ember.A(record.get(key)).mapBy('id'); problem is you can't do that in b15, that should read, I believe, json[payloadKey] = Ember.A(record.attr(key)).mapBy('id');

Comment: see https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/issues/226 as it has apparently already been raised with them. You could always fork it and change it as I indicated and see if that works until they release a more permanent fix.